# CSV import with progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I'm using this script for importing a csv file to mysql database.

How can i display a progress bar for importing a csv file to db using jquery and php ?

I don't need te actual code, just some infos.

Thanks in advance.

```
    if ( $request->get( $_POST["action"] ) == "import" ) {

        $file = $upload->file_upload( "import", "media/import" );

        if ( file_exists( DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file ) ) {

            $file   = DIR_UPLOAD_PHOTO . "/media/import/" . $file;

            try {
                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST."; dbname=".DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);

            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }

            $handle = fopen( $file, "r" );
            $delimiter = '|';

            $dbh->beginTransaction();


            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO products SET title = :title, price = :price
                                               ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                                                           title = :title, price = :price"
            );


            fgets($handle);

            $rows = count(file($file));

            while ($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) {

                    $line = array_map('trim', $line);


                    $stmt->bindParam(':title',          $line[0], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':price',          $line[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);

                    $stmt->execute();


            }


            $dbh->commit();
            fclose($handle);
            $dbh = null;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you have tried? There are so many tutorials on this that it would be nice to know the method that you're trying so we can help you more easily.

Comment: I just need some infos to start ..not the actual code

Comment: If you need info to start you should Google for the tutorials.

Comment: that could use some improvement. there's no point in binding and rebinding your variables inside the loop. bind them OUTSIDE the loop

Comment: @Marc B The insert will not work if i bind them outside the loop

Comment: `bind($foo); bind($bar)`, then `while(list($foo, $bar) = fgetcsv(...))`

Answer (score 0):

At last in MariaDB you get some Status-Information this way (don't know if it works in MySQL as well):

- Fork the `INSERT INTO ...` Statement in an other process
- and run it.
- Use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in your main thread to get the Status of the `INSERT` Statement.